# Relative file paths in included begin_src blocks

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-babel

I have this file structure:

```
.
├── main.org
└── part1
    ├── img/
    └── part.org
```

main.org:

```
* Main file
** Part 1
#+include:part1/part.org
```

part1.org:

```
#+begin_src gnuplot :exports none :results file :file ./img/fig1.png
plot x**2
#+end_src

#+name: fig1
#+caption: Plot
[[./img/fig1.png]]
```

I want to be able to export to latex both `main.org` and `part.org` (basically what [org-thesis](https://github.com/dangom/org-thesis) does) and also to generate figures only in their respective `part*/img/` folder.

The problem is: when I export `main.org` org-mode changes `[[./img/fig1.png]]` to `[[part1/img/fig1.png]]` but ignores `:file ./img/fig1.png`.

If I create `img/` on the same level as `main.org` then org-mode correctly generates figures in that folder (but tries to use those in `part1/img/`).

So is there a way for `:file filename` to have the same behaviour as `[[filename]]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to achieve what you want within Org mode (one can never discount the ability of Org mode to solve problems like this!). But it might be simpler to use external facilities.

My suggestion would be to add an `img/` directory at the main level, and then add symbolic links to all the image files. `main.org` would access them as `./img/figN.png` through the symbolic links, whereas each part would access its figures using the same name, `./img/figN.png`, but as the actual file. The structure would look like this:

```
.
|-- img
|   |-- fig1.png -> ../part1/img/fig1.png
|   `-- fig2.png -> ../part2/img/fig2.png
|-- part1
|   |-- img
|   |   `-- fig1.png
|   `-- part1.org
|-- part2
|   |-- img
|   |   `-- fig2.png
|   `-- part2.org
`-- main.org
```

The symbolic links in the top `img/` directory can be created in bulk with a command like this:

```
 find ./*/img -type f -name '*.png' | xargs bash -c 'ln -sf "${@/./..}" ./img' link
```

executed at the top level of the tree (the same level as `main.org`). N.B. This command will *NOT* work if the pathnames contain spaces (i.e. no `part 1` or `fig 2.png` allowed); it's probably possible to deal with that limitation but it's left as an exercise for the interested reader (adding `-print0` to the `find` command and `-r0` to the `xargs` command is *NOT* enough).

The pieces of the command can be understood as follows:

- `find ./*/img -type f -name '*.png'` finds all the normal files (`-type f`) with names matching `*.png` in all the `img/` subdirs one level down from the current directory (`./*/img`). It prints them out separated by spaces.
- `xargs bash -c 'ln -sf  "${@/./..}" ./img' echo` passes the accumulated pathnames to a shell which modifies each one by changing the initial `./` to an initial `../` (see the tree above for the necessity of this step) and then passes them all to a `ln -sf ... ./img` command which creates the symbolic links (`-s`), forcing the creation even if a link exists already (`-f`).

Hope this helps, even though it has nothing to do with emacs!